# center align html5 video doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, safari

I'm making a super basic webpage that just plays a video, and it aligns in the very center of the page for every browser except Safari, where it is pushed to the bottom left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<head>
    <title> page title </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div class="video">
<iframe src=" /*i'm not including the video link for privacy reasons*/ width="700" height="525"     frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</body>

<style type="text/css">
.video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

</html>
```

Has anyone run into this problem before? It seems pretty basic, but I just don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` property only works in Safari with the `-webkit-` prefix:

```
.video {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o3deueqj/2/)

You can refer to [**Can I Use**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) to see browser support

Comment: yes yes this is it thank you very much for taking the time to answer such a simple question . . .  : )